# How to dynamically use month as part of a timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm looking to add partitions for the next X months whenever this script is run. At the moment, the script is updated manually with each run, to create partitions for the next 9 months:

```
ALTER TABLE AUDIT_TBL
ADD PARTITION "YEAR2020_M04" VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2020-05-01 00:00:00') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED;
```

However, I'd like to get the current month, and change both the partition name and timestamp accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a PL/SQL procedure with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command to execute a string as a SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAKE_PARTITIONS(months_number NUMBER)
DECLARE
  v_nextMonthDate DATETIME := SYSDATE;
  v_year NUMBER;
  v_monthCode CHAR(2);
  v_limitDate DATETIME;
  v_nextMonth NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR v_nextMonth IN 0..months_number LOOP
    v_year := EXTRACT(year FROM v_nextMonthDate);  
    v_monthCode := TO_CHAR(v_nextMonthDate, 'MM');
    v_limitDate := TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(v_nextMonthDate, 1),'mon');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "ALTER TABLE AUDIT_TBL ADD PARTITION 'YEAR:1_M:2' VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP ':3') SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED"
    USING v_year, v_monthCode, v_limitDate;

    v_nextMonthDate := ADD_MONTHS(v_nextMonthDate, 1);
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Note that my PL/SQL is a bit rusty, so I'm not sure if that compiles without a problem, but this is the idea.

You call this function like that:

```
BEGIN
  MAKE_PARTITIONS(5);  
END;
```

or like that

```
EXEC MAKE_PARTITIONS(5);
```